# Elasticsearch mappings generated differently for different deployments for my spring project

Tags: spring, java-8, elasticsearch-5, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

In my spring project, I use annotations to define elasticsearch fields. As far as I understand, elasticsearch mappings are generated on startup of the app based on those annotations. However, mappings generated are different for different deployments.

I am running spring project with Java 8 and ElasticSearch 5.5.0.

Annotations:

```java
@Size(min = MINIMUM_LENGTH_NAME, max = MAXIMUM_LENGTH_NAME)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
@Field(store = Store.YES)
@Field(name = "name_forSort", normalizer = @Normalizer(definition = "lowercase"))
@SortableField(forField = "name_forSort")
private String name;
```

Expected mappings for name:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name" : {
        "type" : "text",
        "store" : true
      },
      "name_forSort" : {
        "type" : "keyword",
        "norms" : true,
        "normalizer" : "lowercase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Mappings for the problematic deployment:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
       "name" : {
         "type" : "text",
         "fields" : {
           "keyword" : {
             "type" : "keyword",
             "ignore_above" : 256
           }
         }
       },
       "name_forSort" : {
         "type" : "text",
         "fields" : {
           "keyword" : {
             "type" : "keyword",
             "ignore_above" : 256
           }
         }
       },
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: One thing I've been trying to figure out is why those can be different if they are generated purely by those annotations. Is there any other config that may contribute to this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by initiating a new ES instance followed by a reindex. It seems the weird mapping was caused by a previously failed reindex with corrupted data.

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch 5.5.0 is old, and you did not specify, which Spring Data Elasticsearch (which I will call SDE for brevity) version you rare using. The solution I show in this answer is tested with the current SDE 3.2.0.RC1 which supports Elasticsearch 6.8.2, but as fa as could see in the source code of SDE, this functionality is available in old versions and should work with your version as well.

In your code there are problems:

- You are mixing different annotations that you put on the property, but only the second `@Field` annotation comes from SDE. `@Field(store = Store.YES)` is not from SDE, the correct annotation has a `store` attribute that is of type `boolean`. Neither `@Column` nor `@SortableField` are known to SDE and will be ignored when building the mapping.
- The correct way to use a field multiple times in an index with different settings is by [using *fields* mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/multi-fields.html) (as you see in the link this was already in 5.5). This is supported by SDE with the `@MultiField` annotation.

I have run a minimal example with the following files:

**normalizer.json**

```
{
    "index": {
        "analysis": {
            "normalizer": {
                "lowercase": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "char_filter": [],
                    "filter": [ "lowercase" ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Person.java**

```
package com.sothawo.springdataelastictest;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Field;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.FieldType;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.InnerField;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.MultiField;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Setting;

@Document(indexName = "person-test")
@Setting(settingPath = "normalizer.json")
public class Person {
    @Id private Long id;

    @MultiField(mainField = @Field(store = true, type = FieldType.Text),
                otherFields = {
                    @InnerField(suffix = "forSort", 
                                normalizer = "lowercase", 
                                type = FieldType.Keyword)
                })
    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**PersonRepository.java**

```
package com.sothawo.springdataelastictest;

import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.ElasticsearchRepository;

public interface PersonRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Person, Long> {}
```

Starting up a Spring Boot application with these classes creates the following index:

```
{
  "person-test": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "person": {
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "store": true,
            "fields": {
              "forSort": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "normalizer": "lowercase"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "provided_name": "person-test",
        "creation_date": "1563903601344",
        "analysis": {
          "normalizer": {
            "lowercase": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase"
              ],
              "type": "custom",
              "char_filter": []
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "WhSFtV-xQ8acXxX6R0gLyg",
        "version": {
          "created": "6070299"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.
The problem was solved by initiating a new ES instance followed by a reindex. It seems the weird mapping was caused by a previously failed reindex with corrupted data.
I will look into the annotations and correct them base on your suggestions.
Thanks again.